# Override UIView's frame

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

I have subclassed UIView, but I need to prevent the frame from changing, so I tried overriding the `setFrame:` method and just ignoring the value passed, and creating my own CGRect base on `self.superview` and passing it to `[super setFrame:`

How can I make the UIView's frame unchangeable? (from within the subclass)

Comment: Did that not work? Sounds like a good approach to me.

Comment: Nope I think it's because frame is set before there's a superview

Comment: I need an `addedToSuperview` method

Comment: how about `willMoveToSuperview:` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Step1: Override setFrame to do nothing.

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)newRect
{
}
```

Step 2: Move your semi-static frame setting into your overridden version of `willMoveToSuperview:` to get a valid superview reference.

```
- (void)willMoveToSuperview:(UIView *)newSuperview
{
   CGRect newFrame = newSuperview.frame;
   //manipulate the frame here
   [super setFrame:newFrame];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how I could have missed this method :)

Comment: heh, glad this works for you -- one addition though, make sure that newSuperview is actually not nil when deriving the frame... cheers and happy egg hunting

Answer (score 0):

Wait, can't you just set the autoresizingMask to 0? I though that would prevent the view from getting resized when parent view is resized (tried it as well, and seemed to work for me).

Comment: My subclass is more like an alert view, so I want it to always be in the middle of the screen.